# Citation call-out in definition header

Tags: citing, theorems

I'm using a break theoremstyle and I would like to do something like this

[image]

but my code

```
 \usepackage[polish]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[right=2.7cm,left=3.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{definicja}{Definicja}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{definicja} \cite[p.~71]{Doman}
Niech dany będzie zbiór $k$ punktów na płaszczyźnie, tzn. $\mathcal{K}_0=\{P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k\}$. 
Kreśląc wszystkie możliwe okręgi i proste z danych punktów oraz wyznaczając ich części wspólne otrzymamy nowe punkty $P_{k+1}, P_{k+2}, \ldots, P_{k+l}$, gdzie $l \in \mathbb{N}$.  \\
Zbiór złożony z punktów $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k$ oraz z punktów $P_{k+1}, P_{k+2}, \ldots, P_{k+l}$ nazywa się zbiorem punktów konstruowalnych i oznacza się go jako $\mathcal{K}_1$. 
\end{definicja}
\end{document}
```

Don't create it :C

Comment: Please make your code a compilable and minimal example.

Comment: Please tell us how the `definicja` environment is set up. Do you use a theorem-related package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem`?

Comment: I'm using  \usepackage{ntheorem}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're also using a citation management package such as `natbib`. If that's the case, consider using the following solution:

```
 \begin{definicja}[\protect{\citealp[p.~71]{Doman}}]
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
 \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
 \usepackage[polish]{babel}
 \let\lll\relax % to avoid conflict with amssmyb package
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage[right=2.7cm,left=3.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}    
 \usepackage{ntheorem}
 \theoremstyle{break}
 \newtheorem{definicja}{Definicja}[section]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example

\begin{definicja}[\protect{\citealp[p.~71]{Doman}}]
Niech dany będzie zbiór $k$ punktów na płaszczyźnie, tzn.\ 
$\mathcal{K}_0=\{P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k\}$.
Kreśląc wszystkie możliwe okręgi i proste z danych punktów oraz 
wyznaczając ich części wspólne otrzymamy nowe punkty $P_{k+1}, 
P_{k+2}, \ldots, P_{k+l}$, gdzie $l \in \mathbb{N}$.\\
Zbiór złożony z punktów $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k$ oraz z punktów 
$P_{k+1}, P_{k+2}, \ldots, P_{k+l}$ nazywa się zbiorem punktów 
konstruowalnych i oznacza się go jako $\mathcal{K}_1$.
\end{definicja}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request: To achieve your additional formatting requirement, I suggest you add the following code to the preamble (*after* loading the `ntheorem` package, of course):

```
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{break}%
{\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
     ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
{\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
     ##1\ ##2\ \mdseries [##3]\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thx, but I need [] bracket.

Comment: @Blazej - I've posted an addendum to address your follow-up request.

Comment: Sure, Can I ask for one more thing. 
How to change [2, p. 71] on [2, str. 71], because I need polish version it. 
Thanks. Of course I delete all my comments ;)

Comment: @Blazej - Simply change `\citealp[p.~71]{Doman}}]` to `\citealp{[str.~71]{Doman}}]`. :-)

Comment: Could me give a favour?
How to generate that same effect with asmthm ?
And how create sth like this 
[pro. 2 str. 12] 
[zob. 2 str. 12]

Comment: @Blazej - please post a *new* query. That way, it'll be seen by many more people. Thanks.